# Test Explorer in Visual Studio 2022 is not working

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2022

When I click Run All tests in view, it's running but not showing that tests are passed or failed. I mean it's showing blue marks as shown before]

[image: When I click Run All tests in view, it's running but not showing that tests are passed or failed. I mean it's showing blue marks as shown before]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try invoking them by running the command in console

```
dotnet test
```

If that doesn't help it could be that the `NUnit 3 Test Adapter` is missing and you need to reinstall it.

I also suggest you to view the error output of your test runner to get some more information by opening the output panel (by clicking on view-->output), then choosing "tests" (from the 'Show output from' dropdown) and you'll get the specific problem.

Comment: Bro, YOU ARE GENIUS. I have used dotnet test and console outputed that I need to install .NET Core 3 runtime. I installed it and now it's working. Thankss )))

Comment: Great, I'm glad it's working! would appreciate if you can accept the answer as accepted if it helped you

Comment: Yeah I accepted ), it's my first week on stackoverflow so my questions seems like wierd

Comment: Sukhrob thank you for question. I had the same problem with xUnit project!
@RanTurner thank you for this lifesaving tip! "dotnet test" command has revealed all problems!

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't figure out why the test was being skipped and I saw no errors, but changing the output source helped me.

Comment: For me, I already had NUnit3TestAdapter Nuget package installed (v4.2.1), but the latest Visual Studio 2022 update (to v17.6.2) broke NUnit3TestAdapter so I upgraded to the most recent NUnit3TestAdapter (v4.5.0) and my unit tests started working again.

Comment: Executing this command highlighted that a constructor I was using was preventing the running of the tests in the class. Add a new constructor that takes no parameters and everything runs as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to find this is to check the Output window.  Once you've triggered an action from the Test Explorer, there should be a Tests pane in the Output Window, and it likely would have also given you an answer.

For example:
[image: Output window set to show output from Tests]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

VS 2019 & VS 2022: I had to uncheck this box under Test > Options

Comment: It would be nice to have an explanation as to why this answer was given. It doesn't work as stated and actually removed my tests from the explorer.

Answer (score 1):

It resolved for me installing "NUnit Test Generator VS2022" extension in my IDE.
PS: Had to clean and Rebuild solution to identify all tests, post plugin installation.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was identical to the post after porting my MSTest suite from VS 2019 to VS 2022. Updating these nuget updates for MSTest is what worked in my case. One more thing to have on the list of possible solutions.

[image: nugets for MSTest]